# How to download bittorrent form ppa?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

I am using this command to try to download qBittorrent

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable`

However, I am getting this error:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,031 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [490 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [781 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [330 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [205 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]
Hit:13 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]    
Ign:15 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease    
Get:16 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release [5,378 B]
Get:17 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release.gpg [801 B]
Get:18 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,317 B]
Get:19 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4/multiverse arm64 Packages [9,065 B]
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:21 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4/multiverse amd64 Packages [12.2 kB]
Get:22 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable/main amd64 Packages [4,887 B]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [704 kB]
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [141 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.5 kB]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [251 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [36.5 kB]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58.3 kB]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal InRelease [17.5 kB]
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Err:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [2,808 B]
Hit:37 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Why does the "bitcoin" repository cause an error for bittorrent, which is something totally different? Obviously, there is something I don't understand here about packages/repositories, but why does this request for many other applications (ubuntu, mongodb, ethereum, etc.)?

Comment: It's a coincidence. Your failure to remove the dead PPA is unrelated to adding a different PPA. Remove the dead PPA, and the error will vanish. Since qbitorrent is in the Ubuntu repositories, you don't need a PPA anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: 3rd party sources (ie. PPAs) are your responsibility to perform checks, ie. are they maintained, trustworthy etc..   A quick check using detail on your paste and I can see the PPA you added doesn't support *focal* (has been ignored since 2018) and should not have been added.. do you perform required security checks before adding the source?

Comment: You don't need to add a PPA to install `qbittorrent` because it is available in the `universe` repository.  You can install it in the software center or using `apt`